# set multiple scope value From ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I've scope object like this:

```
myObject: {
  A: '',
  B: '',
  otherValues: {
    0: {
       myValue: '',
       status: ''
       }
    1: {
       myValue: '',
       status: ''
       }
  }
}
```

I've list of checkbox:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myArray">
<td><input name="{{value.myValue}}" type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="myObject.otherValues[$index].status" 
    ng-click="setFunction(value.myValue,$index)" />
</tr>
```

status is set by ng-model (true,false). I want to set myValue using setFunction.
In my controller i've this function:

```
function setFunction (value,index) {
    $scope.myObject.otherValues[index].myValue= value;
}
```

But generates console error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
How can i resolve it?

Comment: Could you give us some fiddle or plunker?

Comment: I think `otherValues` should be an array instead

Answer (score 1):

Your Json object is missing a comma :

```
myObject: {
  A: '',
  B: '',
  otherValues: {
    0: {
       myValue: '',
       status: ''
       },  //Missing Comma
    1: {
       myValue: '',
       status: ''
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, but the problem is not comma... it was my cut/paste error